# How to modify array such that all keys are increased by 1

Tags: php, arrays, push, key

I have this array

```
$arr[0] = 'zero'
$arr[1] = 'one'
$arr[2] = 'two'
$arr[3] = 'three'
```

I want to be able to push a value in at a certain point and push the keys which follow this new value up by one so ending up with:

```
$arr[0] = 'zero'
$arr[1] = 'one'
$arr[2] = 'my new value' //keys before remain the same, keys after are increased by 1
$arr[3] = 'two'
$arr[4] = 'three'
```

Is there a simple solution which does not involve a `foreach` or is that my only solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array_splice($array, 2, 0, 'my new value');
```

http://php.net/array_splice

Comment: Beaten to it! +1, I had the exact same thing.

Comment: ok, not a trick. Propably I didnt read it carefully :p However, I dont think, I would get to that function, if Im looking for something, that should insert something. Its just worth to keep in mind :)